# OpenAPI Generator handle expired access token globally

Tags: vue.js, openapi-generator

In the context of a Vue.js project, I'm using the Javascript client generated by OpenAPI Generator to make the backend API calls. The authorization is taken care of by setting the ApiClient's `authentications['BearerAuth'].accessToken` property to the JWT access token I'm getting from the backend.

Normally, the JWT gets refreshed before it expires but I'm looking for a way to handle the "expired access token" globally. That is, without checking the status code of every single API request throughout the application. The action for that case would be to log out the user and show him/her the login page.

Does the OpenAPI Generator client provide any way to check the return value of every request for a given value (e.g. `401 Unauthorized`), and call a given function in case that happens? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Hey, have you figured it out?

Comment: Hey @mszan, unfortunately not. I'm still checking the status codes locally.